# IAPClientPaymentException: Application ID initialization fails j2me nokia

Tags: java-me, in-app-purchase, nokia

I just want to know, what can make the IAP prompt this kind of exception "com.nokia.mid.payment.IAPClientPaymentException: Application ID initialization fails" when you test it in the emulator.
Another related question: The documentation says to remove the TEST_MODE.TXT file when pointing it to live server. I removed the text but now I get Security Exception. Whats the workaround for this? I am using java sdk 2.0 and the emulator that came with it.

Comment: I think your chances of finding developers on Stack Overflow with this level of expertise in the Nokia IAP APIs, are pretty slim.  You'd be better asking this on Forum Nokia or whatever it's called these days, where you'll be likely to find developers within Nokia who can help you.